# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. PYTHON_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)

Tags: python, cmake

I'm trying to install this software http://www.openstructure.org/docs/1.4/install/ and I get this error:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
PYTHON_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "_ost_conop" in directory /opt/ost/modules/conop/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_gfx" in directory /opt/ost/modules/gfx/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_img" in directory /opt/ost/modules/img/base/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_img_alg" in directory /opt/ost/modules/img/alg/pymod
    linked by target "ost_gui" in directory /opt/ost/modules/gui/src
    linked by target "_ost_gui" in directory /opt/ost/modules/gui/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_io" in directory /opt/ost/modules/io/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_info" in directory /opt/ost/modules/info/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_seq" in directory /opt/ost/modules/seq/base/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_seq_alg" in directory /opt/ost/modules/seq/alg/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_mol" in directory /opt/ost/modules/mol/base/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_mol_alg" in directory /opt/ost/modules/mol/alg/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_geom" in directory /opt/ost/modules/geom/pymod
    linked by target "_ost_base" in directory /opt/ost/modules/base/pymod

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/ost/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/ost/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I'm guessing I have to pass the path to `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` to cmake but I have no idea what. I have the correct python installed and all other dependencies.

Comment: The very link you shared with us has an explicit example where PYTHON_LIBRARIES is set to the path where homebrew installs Python. Have you followed this? Have you installed all the dependencies from homebrew?

Comment: There was no example of this on that page, that was PYTHON_ROOT. Also I'm not on a mac but on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a question and an answer to that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I took this advice https://askubuntu.com/questions/479260/cmake-can-not-find-pythonlibs and installed the latest cmake (3.4.1) from source. This did not solve the problem and I got the same error. However I did solve it using cmake 3.4, not sure if it made a difference though.

I had to run cmake explicitly showing it PYTHON_LIBRARIES suggested from that same thread.

```
cmake . -DPYTHON_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so
```

It was not simply enough to use

```
export PYTHON_LIBRARIES=/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so
```

and then `cmake .`.

Comment: As I told you passing PYTHON_LIBRARIES to CMake. Exporting the variable makes it a environment variable which is not evaluated by CMake. Maybe you had to delete your cache; this could be triggered by going back to CMake 3.4. Would you mind to give CMake 3.4.1 another try if it is working now? Otherwise it could be a CMake bug.